# MIPS code to look up user input

Tags: arrays, mips

So this is my array [ 1, 3, 6, 2, 8, 4, 9, 11, 5, 14, 9999, 34]. I want to write MIPS code to lookup if an inputted (from user) number is included in the array.

If the inputted number is included, it should output its index.

If the inputted number is not included, it should output "not found".

```
.data # this is a data structure in MIPS

Array:  .word  1, 3, 6, 2, 8, 4, 9, 11, 5, 14, 9999, 34 # this is an array

welcome: .asciiz "Enter an integer"

.text

li $vo, 4

la $a0, welcome

syscall

li $vo, 5

syscall

sw $v0, ($s0)     # saves user input into address at $s0
    addi $s0, $s0, 4          # increments address at $s0 by 4 bytes

   addi $t2, $t2, 1   

  .globl main

 main:
li $t2, 0 # let $t2 be 0

la $t0, Array # load the array "Array"'s base address to register $t0

lw $s0, 0($t0) # load the first element in the "Array", which is Array[0]. 
 loop:
```

Comment: I don't know what syscall #5 is, but I'm assuming what you get from it is a pointer to a string of ASCII (or UTF-8) characters that the user typed in response to "Enter an integer". The first thing you need to do is convert that ASCII string into a simple integer. Do you have the C runtime available? If so, you may be able to use atoi() as a simple converter, as long as the user input is nul-terminated. If not, have fun doing that in assembly. Once you've converted the number from a string to an integer, then you'll be ready to loop over your array & compare each value to the integer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of bug and I have edited for you and write some simple `if/else` to determine the number entered by user is equal or not within the array, it test only one integer at a time in order to check the whole array you need to write a loop which use the same principal  that I have write here. good luck.

```
.globl main
.data # this is a data structure in MIPS

Array:  .word  1, 3, 6, 2, 8, 4, 9, 11, 5, 14, 9999, 34 # this is an array

welcome: .asciiz "Enter an integer"
notfound:.asciiz "Not found"

.text
 main:
li  $v0, 4          #print string

la  $a0, welcome
syscall

li  $v0, 5          #read integer
syscall
move  $t1, $v0


la  $t0, Array      # load the array "Array"'s base address to register $t0

lw  $s0, 0($t0)     # load the first element in the "Array", which is Array[0]. 
beq $t1,$s0, L1     #branch to L1 if t1 = s0
li  $v0,4
la  $a0, notfound
syscall
b  end
L1: 
move    $a1,$s0
li  $v0,4
syscall 
end:    
li $v0,10       #exit the program
syscall
```